# Can I use {} instead of <?php ?> without Laravel?

Tags: php, syntax

When using Laravel, you can use `{ $variable }` instead of `<?php echo $variable; ?>`, can you do this when you are using PHP without Laravel?

Comment: Yes it is possible. A bit more info would have been useful in providing a fuller answer. But the `{$var}` is PHP and not specific to Laravel

Comment: This is called template engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I got you right. You want to put variable elements inside your HTML template files without using the ugly "`<?php echo ...; ?>`" ?

What you need is a [Template engine](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/top-5-php-template-engines/). You could get one of these ready-to-use template system and learn how to use them (but they don't have the exact behaviour you describe) or you could code your own parser.

I personnally made my own HTML parser, its behaviour is adapted to the use I make of it. For what you need, all you need is to read HTML files and replace using a regexp

```
^\{ (.+) \}$
```

with

```
$($1)
```